# Is Disk Utility encryption the same as dm-crypt?

Tags: 12.04, usb, encryption, disk-utility, dmcrypt

I have found the following 2 minute video which shows how to encrypt a usb drive using ubuntu's disk utility app:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J_g-W6hrkNA

My question is, is that method using dm-crypt, or some other technique for encrypting the drive?

Comment: I personally prefer truecrypt because of it's cross-platform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

gnome-disc-utility (or palimpsest as it was once named) uses [Linux Unified Key Setup](http://code.google.com/p/cryptsetup/)  which is a disk encryption specification. It is an enhanced version of [cryptsetup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptsetup), using [dm-crypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dm-crypt) as the disk encryption backend. From the 1st link:

> **Linux Unified Key Setup (LUKS)**
>
> Cryptsetup is a utility used to conveniently setup disk encryption based on dm-crypt kernel module. These include plain dm-crypt volumes, LUKS volumes, loop-AES and TrueCrypt compatible format. Project also includes veritysetup utility used to conveniently setup dm-verity block integrity checking kernel module.
>
> **LUKS Design**
>
> LUKS is the standard for Linux hard disk encryption. By providing a standard on-disk-format, it does not only facilitate compatibility among distributions, but also provides secure management of multiple user passwords. In contrast to existing solution, LUKS stores all setup necessary setup information in the partition header, enabling the user to transport or migrate his data seamlessly.
>
> LUKS was designed according to TKS1, a template design developed in TKS1 for secure key setup. LUKS closely reassembles the structure recommended in the TKS1 paper, but also adds meta data for cipher setup management and LUKS also supports for multiple keys/passphrases.

- More detail in [this topic](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39306/how-secure-is-ubuntus-default-full-disk-encryption) on security stack exchange.